# Vertical scrolling in iScroll carousel

Tags: css, carousel, iscroll, vertical-scrolling, iphone-web-app

/**** UPDATE ****/

I figured it out. Turns out iScroll has an option called: "options.eventPassthrough"

> options.eventPassthrough
>   Sometimes you want to preserve native vertical scroll but being able to add an horizontal iScroll (maybe a carousel). Set this to true and the iScroll area will react to horizontal swipes only. Vertical swipes will naturally scroll the whole page.
>   See event passthrough demo on a mobile device. Note that this can be set to 'horizontal' to inverse the behavior (native horizontal scroll, vertical iScroll). 
>   via http://iscrolljs.com/

/**** ORIGINAL POST ****/

I am building a mobile website where the user can swipe up and down to view content. And swipe left and right to change views.

When in the mobile web browser, I can't swipe up and down. Any ideas?

http://shaloon.com/scrolltest/

Everything works as expect on the desktop. I am using iScroll5.

Thank you!

Comment: As i see it's not working so well on desktop either. The scrolling is not pending on the height of window now.

Comment: The site is only for mobile web, so I restricted the height on desktop to that of the iPhone. (I am just building it as an interaction test).

Comment: you should write your solution as an answer